# How to use Tensorflow on our own data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm a beginner in Tensor flow. I'm trying to feed my own data set by using tensor flow place holders. With a lot of research online I've figured out that using tf.data.DataSet is an ideal way to give our own data. But I'm just curious on how to solve the following issue:I'm using a glass identification data set with 10 independent variables and one dependent varible [https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/glass.data][1]

here's a glimpse of my data:

```
    Id  RI  Na  Mg  Al  Si  K   Ca  Ba  Fe  Type
count   213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000  213.000000
mean    108.000000  1.518353    13.406761   2.676056    1.446526    72.655023   0.499108    8.957934    0.175869    0.057277    2.788732
std 61.631972   0.003039    0.818371    1.440453    0.499882    0.774052    0.653035    1.426435    0.498245    0.097589    2.105130
min 2.000000    1.511150    10.730000   0.000000    0.290000    69.810000   0.000000    5.430000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
25% 55.000000   1.516520    12.900000   2.090000    1.190000    72.280000   0.130000    8.240000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
50% 108.000000  1.517680    13.300000   3.480000    1.360000    72.790000   0.560000    8.600000    0.000000    0.000000    2.000000
75% 161.000000  1.519150    13.830000   3.600000    1.630000    73.090000   0.610000    9.180000    0.000000    0.100000    3.000000
max 214.000000  1.533930    17.380000   3.980000    3.500000    75.410000   6.210000    16.190000   3.150000    0.510000    7.000000
```

Here's my code:

```
r,c = data.shape

n_inputs = c - 1

n_hidden1 = int(input('No. of nodes in hidden layer 1 \n'))

n_hidden2 = int(input('No. of nodes in hidden layer 2 \n'))

y_new = np.array(data['Type']-1)
y_cat = to_categorical(y_new)


n_outputs = y_cat.shape[1]



#1.1) Using Place holders to define shape of the variables

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X") # We don't know no. of rows yet but we know the no. of columns given by n_inputs

y= tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None), name="y")


# 1.2) Using name scopes and creating each layer
# A dense layer with sequential connections is created

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):

    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1", activation = tf.nn.relu, reuse= tf.AUTO_REUSE) #First hidden layers takes X as input

    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2", activation = tf.nn.relu, reuse= tf.AUTO_REUSE) # Second hidden layer takes first hidden layer as input

    logits_out = tf.layers.dense(hidden2,n_outputs,name="outputs",reuse= tf.AUTO_REUSE) # Output layer 



# 1.3) Defining a Loss function with a proper name scope

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits_out)
    #softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits_out)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")



# 1.4) Choose a good optimizer

learning_rate = float(input('Please choose a learning rate \n'))

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)


# 1.5) Specifying how to evaluate the model

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits_out, y,1)

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))



#Create a global initializer

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

ss = StandardScaler()

```
X = data.drop([ 'Type'], axis=1)

ss.fit(X)

X_scaled = ss.transform(X)


n_cols = X_scaled.shape[1]


strt_pos = 0; end_pos = 0

def next_batch(batch_size, iteration):
    '''  Returns batch of feature and target variables   based on index values   '''

    if iteration==0:
        strt_pos = 0; 
        end_pos = batch_size

        X_batch = X_scaled[strt_pos:end_pos]
        y_batch = y_cat[strt_pos:end_pos]    
    else:
        strt_pos = iteration * batch_size
        end_pos = strt_pos + batch_size

        X_batch = X_scaled[strt_pos:end_pos]
        y_batch = y_cat[strt_pos:end_pos]



    return np.array(X_batch), np.array(y_batch)




n_epochs = int(input('Choose no. of epochs \n')) # Choose no. of epochs for training

batch_size = int(input('Choose max batch size \n')) # Choose batch size for training


training_size = float(input('Choose the training size \n'))

total_training_size = int(r * training_size)



with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for iteration in range(total_training_size // batch_size):
            X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(batch_size, iteration)
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_scaled, y: y_cat})
        print(epoch, "Train accuracy: ", acc_train, "Val accuracy: ", acc_val)
```

The "data" variable is my data frame with 213 rows and 11 columns up on choosing all the required values, I get the following error:

```
Choose no. of epochs 
20
Choose max batch size 
20
Choose the training size 
0.7
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-929e743f5882> in <module>()
     17         for iteration in range(total_training_size // batch_size):
     18             X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(batch_size, iteration)
---> 19             sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
     20         acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
     21         acc_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_scaled, y: data['Type']})

C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __hash__(self)
   1487     def __hash__(self):
   1488         raise TypeError('{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be'
-> 1489                         ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1490 
   1491     def __iter__(self):

TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

As you can see I've implemented my own version of next_batch, I'm not sure whether it's returning exactly what the tensor flow is expecting. I'm not at all clear on the type of data "feed_data" is expecting. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S: Thank you for reading through such a long post, but I had no other choice than to give all this information.

Comment: I need help on this very badly... I'd really appreciate any kind of support